# How to update batch weights in back propagation

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

How gradient descent algorithm updates the batch weights in the **back propagation** method?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3):

It is really easy once you understand the algorithm.

```
New Weights = Old Weights - learning-rate x Partial derivatives of loss function w.r.t. parameters
```

Let's consider a neural network with two inputs, two hidden neurons, two output neurons.

First, introduce weights and bias to your network. Then, compute total net input for hidden layer, as such

```
net_{h1} = w_1 * i_1 + w_2 * i_2 + b_1 * 1
```

Do the same for all other hidden layers.

Next, we can now calculate the error for each output neuron using the squared error function and sum them to get the total error.

[image]

Hereinafter, you will have to calculate the partial derivative of the total network error with respect to the previous weights, to find out how each weights affects the network. I have included a visual to help with your understanding.

I strongly suggest you go through this [beginner friendly introduction to back-propagation](https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/) to have a firm grasp of the concept. I hope my beginner post help you get started in the journey of Machine Learning!

[image]